# Tkinter Pillow, i cant see pic

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

What I'm trying to do is;

1- Select a picture and save it in a new directory by giving it a 'model no' and 'stock code'.

2- Then display the picture on the screen with this new name.

The first step is successful. However, when I invited him to the picture screen, I could not get the picture even though it made room for him. What am I doing wrong .. !!

thanks in advance for your help.
Here are my codes.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

model_no = "Y101"
stock_code = "Y101BLACK"
pencere = Tk()

Lframe = LabelFrame(pencere, text=" Resim ", bg="#eeeeee")
Lframe.grid(row=0, column=6, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky='wens', pady=5, padx=5)

def resimal():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:\\Python34\\build",title = "Select file",
                                                filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    print("filename: ", filename)
    fln = filename.split("/")[-1]
    print("fln", fln)

    backup_directory = ["{}\\Documents\\Ortak Yedek\\{}".format(os.path.expanduser('~'), model_no)]

    try:
        os.makedirs(os.sep.join(backup_directory))  # Indexing from List to Backup
    except OSError:
        pass

    if filename:
        shutil.copy2(filename, os.sep.join(backup_directory)) # Backup / import directories
    else:
        return

    try:
        os.rename("{}\\{}".format(os.sep.join(backup_directory), fln),
                  "{}\\{}.jpg".format(os.sep.join(backup_directory), stock_code))
    except FileExistsError:
        print("error")

    backup_directory = ["{}\\Documents\\Ortak Yedek\\{}".format(os.path.expanduser('~'), model_no)]
    picture = "{}\\{}.jpg".format(os.sep.join(backup_directory), stock_code)

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(picture))

    panel = Label(Lframe, image=img)

    panel.grid(row=1, column=0)

take_picture = Button(Lframe, text="Take Picture", width=10, command=resimal)
take_picture.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')


mainloop()
```

Comment: This is way too much code for the problem you have described. Please can you provide a **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable** example which complies with our standards of an MCVE found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try searching this site. There are many questions and answers related to images not showing up

Comment: Solved the problem with correct search. Thanks so much